# showing and hiding content with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

kindly see this theme. When click on "About Us, Contact Us, Newsletter" it shows another div content except present content and clicking close button it disappear. How to do this? Actually I want the code to do in this way.....

http://abyadwaswad.com/Vipe/index-image.html

Comment: There is no theme. Please provide the code

Comment: Theme has been  added :)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the theme and/or the code, we can't do much more than giving you an example code. This one requires jQuery but I'm sure you could also do that in standard JavaScript.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-1">Menu item 1</li>
    <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-2">Menu item 2</li>
    <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-3">Menu item 3</li>
</ul>
<div id="menu-content">
    <div id="menu-content-1">
        This is the content of menu #1.
    </div>
    <div id="menu-content-2" hidden="hidden">
        This is the content of menu #2.
    </div>
    <div id="menu-content-3" hidden="hidden">
        This is the content of menu #3.
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
/** Wait until jQuery is ready */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var menu_items = jQuery("#menu").find("li");
    /** Execute script if a link within the menu has been clicked */
    menu_items.click(function() {
        /** The ID (in this example number 1, 2 or 3) of the clicked menu item.
         *  which we need to display the corresponding content.
         */
        var menu_item_id = jQuery(this).attr("id").replace("menu-item-");

        /** We hide every menu item content */
        menu_items.hide();

        /** And finally we display the content referred by the clicked menu item */
        jQuery("#menu").find(".menu-content-" + menu_item_id).show();
    });
});
```

Not tested but should be fine.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem there? Everything seems fine to me.